# BorderPane spacing between nodes

Tags: layout, javafx, javafx-8

Is it possible to set a spacing between nodes on a `BorderPane`? The Swing-equivalent would be hgap and vgap on `BorderLayout`.

I didn't find anything in the documentation and the only viable workaround I can think of would be to selectively set margins on the child nodes to replicate the effect.

Comment: In HBox & VBox, setPadding defines the gap between each node, but in BorderPane only defines the gap between the BorderPane and its Parent, so my guess is that you will have to use BorderPane.setMargin for each one of the nodes inside it

Comment: In HBox and VBox you call setSpacing() to define the gap between elements. setPadding() on BorderPane and Vbox/HBox works exactly the same.

Answer (score 16):

```
Insets insets = new Insets(10);
BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
    
Node topNode = new Label("TOP");
bp.setTop(topNode);
BorderPane.setMargin(topNode, insets);

Node centerNode = new Label("CENTER");
bp.setCenter(centerNode);
BorderPane.setMargin(centerNode, insets);

Node bottomNode = new Label("BOTTOM");
bp.setBottom(bottomNode);
BorderPane.setMargin(bottomNode, insets);
```

*Be aware: this will put a spacing of 20 (10 from top and 10 from center) between top and center.
Similar for the spacing between center and bottom.*

The documentation

> public static void setMargin(Node child, Insets value)
>
> Sets the margin for the child when contained by a border pane. If set, the border pane will lay it out with the margin space around it. Setting the value to null will remove the constraint.

Answer (score -4):

It's possible to set the padding:

In JFX:

```
<BorderPane>
   <padding>
      <Insets top="10" right="10" bottom="10" left="10"/>
   </padding>
</BorderPane>
```

In code:

```
@FXML
private BorderPane borderPane;    
...
this.borderPane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
```

Comment: This will not set the gap in between the elements.